# Trying to use meteor up on digital ocean

Tags: javascript, deployment, meteor, digital-ocean

I have a digital ocean droplet that I am trying to deploy the most basic of meteor apps to, but I am getting a failing response. Any idea why this is happening?

UPDATE: added entire output

```
 Anderss-iMac:microscope-deploy anderskitson$ mup deploy

Meteor-UP : Production Quality Meteor Deployments
--------------------------------------------------

Bundling Started: /Users/anderskitson/sites/microscope

Started TaskList: Deploying App
[bray.anderskitson.ca] uploading bundle
[bray.anderskitson.ca] uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[bray.anderskitson.ca] setting up env vars
[bray.anderskitson.ca] setting up env vars: SUCCESS
[bray.anderskitson.ca] invoking deployment process
[bray.anderskitson.ca] invoking deployment process: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    Warning: Permanently added 'bray.anderskitson.ca,162.243.52.235' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
    npm WARN package.json http-proxy@1.0.0 No repository field.
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
    stop: Unknown instance: 
    bash: line 46: wait-for-mongo: command not found
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

    > fibers@1.0.1 install /opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
    > node ./build.js

    `linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
    Binary is fine; exiting
    fibers@1.0.1 node_modules/fibers
    meteor start/running, process 10373
    wait for mongo(5 minutes) to initiaze
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Completed TaskList: Deploying App
```

Comment: Did you run `mup setup` first?

Comment: @Akshat yes I did and everything worked for the setup.

Comment: Could you post the entire output not just the bit below what failed

Comment: @Akshat ok I've added the entire output above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into same problem and I figured out that this command wasn't fired really well

`sudo npm install -g forever userdown wait-for-mongo`

and I manually did that so I can see wait-for-mongo a valid command, 
see if that helps you too.